# Excel: Nested if statement is too long

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wrote this IF statement (IF=ALS), but it's too long.

Any idea what might be a solution?

```
=ALS(K2="Soul Shakers";"urban, tropical";ALS(K2="Dunya";"iets anders”;ALS(K2=“Rakka”;”urban, tropical, allround”;ALS(K2=“Ravenous”;”house, techno”;ALS(K2=“DJ Yolotanker”;”allround”;ALS(K2=“Black Mamba”;”urban, tropical”;ALS(K2=“Nico Morano”;”house, techno, underground”;ALS(K2=“Cedex & Higher Underground”;”drum & bass”;ALS(K2=“Leesa”;”house, techno, underground”;ALS(K2=“Station Earth”;”drum & bass”;ALS(K2=“MC Mota”;”drum & bass”;ALS(K2=“Mr_Fuzz”;”urban, tropical, future”;ALS(K2=“Polar Youth”;”urban, future”;ALS(K2=“Skyve”;”allround, urban, tropical, house, drum & bass”;ALS(K2=“Woodie Smalls”;”urban”;ALS(K2=“Jonas Lion;”house, techno, urban, tropical, underground”))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a lookup table like this one:

```
"Soul Shakers" "urban, tropical"
"Dunya"        "iets anders”
"Rakka"        "urban, tropical, allround"
...
"Jonas Lion"   "house, techno, urban, tropical, underground"
```

Now you can use the `VLOOKUP()` like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(K2;your_table_range;2;FALSE)
```

If I am correct you are using Dutch so `VLOOKUP()` will be `VERT.ZOEKEN()`.

Comment: You should probably remove the double quote marks from your table entries, unless you are planning to do something unusual.

Answer (score 0):

The `SWITCH` function does exactly what you're looking for!

```
=SWITCH(K2, "Soul Shakers", "urban, tropical", "Dunya", "iets anders”, ...)
```

- The first argument states what value you're comparing
- Every couple of values (for example `"Soul Shakers", "urban, tropical"`) states the possible value for the input and its corresponding output.
- *Optional:* if the final argument is just one value (and not two), it represents the default output.

Comment: Please note: `SWITCH` is Office-365 exclusive, so won't be available in older version of Excel.  If you *do* have Office-365 then this is a cleaner answer than zipa's

Comment: @Chronocidal Thank you for the important clarification!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with **your** formula is that you have entered it incorrectly.
And the "real" error message would provide that clue.  The real error message was probably something like there cannot be strings > 255 characters within the formula, and **NOT** that the nested IF statement is too long.

- That was the clue that some of your double quotes `"` were really left double quotes `“` or right double quotes `”`.
- Also, you are missing a double quote after your last `ALS` test condition `K2="Jonas Lion,`

That said, a lookup table, as proposed by @zipa, is a more efficient method than a deeply nested `IF`